# About 198.18.0.0/15 segment

Tags: ipv4

What exactly is the use case of 198.18.0.0/15 segment

As per whois records, this segment is reserved as depicting below -

```
NetRange:   198.18.0.0 - 198.19.255.255
CIDR:   198.18.0.0/15
NetName:    SPECIAL-IPV4-BENCHMARK-TESTING-IANA-RESERVED
```

Can i use this segment like the way i use 10/8 as private one in my enterprise network or is this segment for any other special purpose ?

Comment: That is a potentially routable space, There is also [100.64.0.0/10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6598#section-7)

Comment: @NiKiZe: I've seen providers use these address spaces when setting up B2B links. There's also vendors that have apps that intercommunicate, I've seen one using 100.64.

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 6815](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6815), this subnet is used for benchmarking inter-network communications. I would not recommend using this as a private network space.

Comment: why so ? what can be the potential issues if i use 198.18/15 as private segment like the way we all use 10/8

Comment: @GauravKansal 198.15 is a routable address. You sure you don't want to use `1.1.0.0/16`? It's been done before.

Comment: More to the point, it says that such packets may be discarded. Only equipment under test can reasonably be expected to act on packets with these addresses.

Comment: RFC 6815 is an Informational RFC, not a Standards Track RFC.

Comment: @RonMaupin what's the difference between Informational and standard track rfc ?

Comment: See [this fairly comprehensive answer](https://serverfault.com/a/755655/324849).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the special purpose to that net, RFC 6815 is titled [RFC 2544: Use on Production Networks Considered Harmful](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6815) as a warning about such traffic generation until loss test procedures. Some in the ITEF argue so strongly about the need to air gap such a test procedure they added a dedicated private address space, and wrote a statement.

That is not the kind of network I would want to steal addresses from. Not in real networks outside the test lab. Low probability some network gear's RFC2544 test suite takes those addresses and makes something fall over, but potentially high impact.

For as much pristine, never before used address space as you need, implement IPv6.